# How can I automatically export XML source comments to a text document?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xml-comments

I have been using XML comments to document my source code in VB.Net (and C# when I get to). I seem to remember someone telling me a long time ago that there was a way to automatically export the XML comments into a text document or other format for easy reference outside of Visual Studio. Is there? What is it, or are they?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a build setting.

Go into the project properties pages, and turn on "Generate XML Documentation".

For details, see [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4sa0ak0%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I just knew it was something easy I was missing. Thanks!